# Windows 7 - disabling focus change on left click

Tags: windows-7

Is there a possibility to turn off the focus change on left mouse click in windows 7? I would like to click on things in my background, but keep one of the windows constantly focused (it's a game which has built-in pause on focus lose, without ability to disable it). Making a window unable to lose focus would solve my problem as well, but disabling focus change on left click seems more realistic. Note that I don't want the window just to stay on top visually, I want it to have focus.

Comment: I am quite certain there is no such option in Windows. That is a rather serious departure from normal operation and likely to cause problems. It could be done with third party software but I know of none.